# How to permanently enable basic authorization in google chrome 49?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have the following code in a file (camera.htm). When I open such file in Google Chrome 49, Chrome shows the links Up and Down but no video! Then if I click either Up or Down link and then do a refresh page the video shows and the Up and Down links works (the Axis camera moves up and down).
Do not want to have to click beforehand Up or Down button, moreover if I have more than one Axis Camera, I have to click every Up or Down button before for each new camera added in the camera.htm file.
Console in Developer Tools of Chrome shows the error just after opening camera.htm in Chrome:

> Failed to load resource:
>   http://root:root@172.21.2.86/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi the server
>   responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Is there are any setting in Chrome that I must adjust? I know that this has to do with Basic Authorization, but don´t find any solutions. It seems that Chrome accepts the login/password (root/root) after clicking up or down links and doing page refresh, but not when the camera.htm file is newly opened.

thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
       <a href="http://root:root@172.21.2.86/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?move=up">Up</a> | <a href="http://root:root@172.21.2.86/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?move=down">Down</a>
       <img src="http://root:root@172.21.2.86/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that the ability to embed credentials into a URI will be blocked with the release of Chrome M59, and Opera 46 (around June 2017).

In current releases of Chrome, you will recieve a warning in your developer console with "[Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are deprecated, and will be blocked in M59, around June 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.".

Comment: I know that this is going to be deprecated, but I use only Chrome 49 (I use Windows XP, not Vista, Windows 7,..) Reading other posts, it seems that when doing basic auth always sends a 401 response first (to select what type of authentication) and subsequent access does not send 401 responses.